# php@5.6: "cxx11" is not a recognized standard

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm trying to reinstall php 5.6. This is what happens using homebrew:

```
user$ brew reinstall php@5.6
Error: php@5.6: "cxx11" is not a recognized standard
```

How do you fix this issue?

Comment: I think the question is clear, however I'm biased as i have the same problem. I'll try an edit to add details.

Comment: As noted here https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/henkrehorst/homebrew-php/1/499742193 about another library
Run `brew edit php@5.6` then delete "needs: cxx11"

Comment: @Eric;  so now we're really 'brewing@home', lol. <Secret Formula>
This might be fine for the dev crew, but when you encounter this for the first time during an important setup, it's a but daunting to say the least.